# Windows Phone - byte array to BitmapImage converter throws exception

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, windows-phone, converters, bitmapimage

I have a byte array to a BitmapImage converter and it works fine. For tile support within my app, I create a tile from an image (resize and crop it) and save it into my database as byte array. Now, if I want to display this tile with my converter, it throws an exception:

*The component cannot be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x88982F50)*

My method for creating the tile:

```
            WriteableBitmap bmp = new WriteableBitmap(img);

            int height = bmp.PixelHeight;
            int newHeight = 0;

            int width = bmp.PixelWidth;
            int newWidth = 0;

            // calculate new height and new width...

            bmp = bmp.Resize(newWidth, newHeight, WriteableBitmapExtensions.Interpolation.Bilinear);
            bmp = bmp.Crop(0, 0, 336, 336);
            byte[] byteArray = bmp.ToByteArray();

            item.Tile = byteArray;
```

My property for the tile within my entity:

```
    private byte[] _tile;

    [Column(DbType = "IMAGE")]
    public byte[] Tile
    {
        get { return _tile; }
        set { SetProperty(ref _tile, value); }
    }
```

My byte array to BitmapImage converter method:

```
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value != null && value is byte[])
        {
            using (var stream = new MemoryStream((byte[])value))
            {
                stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

                BitmapImage image = new BitmapImage();
                image.SetSource(stream);

                return image;
            }
        }

        return null;
    }
```

I think the problem is that the byte array is saved as Base64 encoded string in the database and there's an error while decoding back to byte array, but I don't know how to solve it.

Comment: At what line is the error thrown?  From what you've written, it appears that the image is stored in a database and then loaded; the problem could be in that process, which you have not described.

Comment: The exception is thrown at `image.SetSource(stream);` within the converter method.

Comment: @c.z "I think the problem is that the byte array is saved as Base64 encoded string in the database and there's an error while decoding back to byte array". Then you should show the code how the data is written to the database and how it is read back. Otherwise, it is really hard to help you, as one would have to reason about errors in code that you have to guess.

Comment: I use the built-in SqlCe database of Windows Phone. The only thing I now is that SqlCe saves binary types as base64 encoded strings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm concerned about your methodology for creating a byte array. Is there some reason you're not using the [SaveJpeg](http://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/windowsphone/develop/system.windows.media.imaging.extensions.savejpeg%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) extension? I don't recognize the WritableBitmap.ToByteArray call you're making. Try instead the following code:

```
int quality = 90;

using (var ms = new System.IO.MemoryStream()) {
    bmp.SaveJpeg(ms, bmp.PixelWidth, bmp.PixelHeight, 0, quality);
    item.Tile = ms.ToArray();
}
```

Comment: `WritableBitmap.ToByteArray` method is part of the WriteableBitmapExtensions. I will try your suggestion, thanks!